# Method compose, in interface Function

Tags: functional-interface

public  Function<V, U> compose(Function<? super V, ? extends T> before)

Can someone explain the way "? super T" works, why we need "super" in this interface to make method more flexible?

I understand that "super" allowed to add an object in case of collections, but how does it work in interface "Function"?

Comment: Does this refer to Java, kotlin ?

Comment: This example is only java, interface Function